# A/C issues, blows cold for couple days then just quits.

Tags: chevrolet, ac, trailblazer

08 Trailblazer v8
A/C stopped blowing cold air. 
Had to pull terminal off to clean fuel intake.  Put terminal back on and A/C was working again.  2days later,  stopped again.  Pulled terminal,  works again. 
Freon is full,  no leaks. 
A/C light comes on when push button. 
Any help please....

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What terminal? The compressor clutch?

Comment: Definitely tell us what terminal you're referring to, otherwise it's very hard to actually help you.